# How to empty select box using jquery when drop down option changes

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a jQuery click function below where it appends a selected value from one select box to another:

```
// Add Button
$('#addbtn').click(function() {
    var selectedOption = jQuery("#studentremain option:selected");
    selectedOption.appendTo($("#studentadd"));
});
```

Now the problem I am having is that if a user changes an option in a drop down menu, then I want the select box `#studentadd` to go back to being empty. Problem is that the values appended into the select box remain, how can I empty the select box?

Below is the jQuery function for when drop down menu changes and my attempt on emptying the select box:

```
$('#sessionsDrop').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#studentadd').val('');     
    }
});
```

HTML/PHP:

Select box:

```
$addSELECT = "";  
$addSELECT .= '<select name="addtextarea" id="studentadd" size="10">';
$addSELECT .= '</select>';
```

Drop down menu:

```
$sessionHTML = '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
$sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;        
$sessionHTML .= '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the contents of an element you can use `empty()`:

```
$('#sessionsDrop').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('#studentadd').empty();     
    }
});
```

Comment: Both methods work, best answer as this came first, upvoted as well

Answer (score 3):

Surely this will do it?

```
$('#studentadd').html('');
```